# How to Rewrite directory url in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have directory like this in my site. => aaa.com/p/folder/

How to change url to => aaa.com/folder/

Note : aaa.com/folder/ doesn't exists in my site. I tried this but get error 404 instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/p/(.+)$ /$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?aaa.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?aaa.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder/index.php [L]
```

Look in your conf file and make sure that AllowOverride is not set to the default of "none". I struggled with this for a while too and the .conf setting was what was causing my biggest headache.

[image]

Comment: what if there is more than one directory /folder/ ?. /p/folder1/ or /p/folder2/ etc. Rewrite to aaa.com/folder1

Comment: Is /p/ the desired "root folder" for the site or are there additional root level physical folders that exist? Or are you only trying to hide the "/p" folder name from view?

Comment: Hide the p folder

Comment: Your original post indicates that "folder" does not physically exist so it would be a virtual named folder. You cannot arbitrarily redirect to many virtual folders (folder1, folder2, etc) from a single source folder :root:/p

Comment: Then if folder1, folder2, etc exist. To get rid /p/ url in htaccess. Replacing with root directory, is that possible ?.